# Regex_Extract Bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the first, second, or third value of a string in bigquery using the regex_extract function.

The string looks like this

```
"testimage International,testimageinternational,002533336564114VoIdiAA"
```

I've been googling around and i'm struggling to get an appropriate regex function.

This is the closest I've gotten `REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, r'[^,]+1') as x`

However although it works great if the string is `test,test1,test2` it doesn't work on the actual string. Any explanation of where i'm going wrong would be super appreciated.

Comment: So, you need 3 different regexps? To get the first, you just need `^[^,]+`. To get the second, and third, use something like `(?:[^,]+,){2}([^,]+)` (change `2` to `1` or remove `{2}` to get the second value.)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew the first value works perfectly, the second selects the first and second string. i'm using `(?:[^,]+,)([^,]+)` and thoughts on how to isolate the second and third values?

Comment: Try `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew you've solved it, for the win!!

Comment: Probably, splitting is still a more natural solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Based on example in your question and suggested regex - I feel you might want to consider simply using SPLIT() as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'testimage International,testimageinternational,002533336564114VoIdiAA' str
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(str, ',')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS first, 
  SPLIT(str, ',')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS second, 
  SPLIT(str, ',')[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS third 
FROM t
```

with result

```sql
Row first                   second                  third    
1   testimage International testimageinternational  002533336564114VoIdiAA
```